# My css file does not expecting effect

Tags: css, jakarta-ee

This is my css file.

```
<style type="text/css">

 .highlightTableRowGreen {
  background-color: green !important;
  font-weight: bold;
  }

 .highlightTableRowRed {
  background-color: red !important;
  font-weight: bold;
  }

 .highlightTableRowGray {
  background-color: gray !important;
  font-weight: bold;
  }

 .yes {
  background-color: red !important; //or whatever color you like.
  }

 </style>
```

My datatable is:

```
<p:dataTable id="articleTable" value="#{articleCtr.listArticle}" var="article" rowKey="#{article.num_article}"
            selection="#{articleCtr.selectedArticle}" selectionMode="single" rowStyleClass="#{(article.quantity) lt 10 ? 'highlightTableRowGreen': null}">
```

Here is my applicationContext.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"

     xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"

    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                          http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.2.xsd 

                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd

                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd">


    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="MyPackage" />

    <mvc:annotation-driven />


    <!-- DAO beans -->
    <bean id="articleDao" class="MyPackage.dao.ArticleDaoImpl"></bean>
    <bean id="storeDao" class="MyPackage.dao.StoreDaoImpl"></bean>
    <bean id="articleFamilyDao" class="MyPackage.dao.ArticleFamilyDaoImpl"></bean>
    <bean id="siteDao" class="MyPackage.dao.SiteDaoImpl"></bean>
    <bean id="thresholdDao" class="MyPackage.dao.ThresholdDaoImpl"></bean>
    <bean id="supplyDao" class="MyPackage.dao.SupplyDaoImpl"></bean>
    <bean id="userDao" class="MyPackage.dao.UserDaoImpl"></bean>
    <bean id="purveyorDao" class="MyPackage.dao.PurveyorDaoImpl"></bean>
    <bean id="billOrderDao" class="MyPackage.dao.BillOrderDaoImpl"></bean>
    <bean id="billDeliveryDao" class="MyPackage.dao.BillDeliveryDaoImpl"></bean>
    <bean id="inventoryDao" class="MyPackage.dao.InventoryDaoImpl"></bean>
    <bean id="soeDao" class="MyPackage.dao.StoreOfEcartDaoImpl"></bean>
    <bean id="orderDao" class="MyPackage.dao.OrderDaoImpl"></bean>
    <bean id="deliveryDao" class="MyPackage.dao.DeliveryDaoImpl"></bean>
    <bean id="operationDAO" class="MyPackage.dao.OperationDaoImpl"></bean>

    <!-- Service beans -->

    <!-- Entity beans -->


    <bean id="jspViewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass"
            value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>


    <bean id="transactionManager"class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />




    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/Supply" />
        <property name="username" value="postgres" />
        <property name="password" value="root" />
    </bean>

    <!-- JNDI DataSource for Java EE environments -->
    <!-- <jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource" jndi-name="java:comp/env/jdbc/petclinic"/> -->

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="MyPackage.model" />
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
            </bean>
        </property>
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="SupplyManagement"></property>
        <property name="persistenceProviderClass">
            <value>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</value>
        </property>
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>


    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/themes/" />


    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
</beans>
```

And finally my web.xml

```
 `<!-- <!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
    "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
    "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" > -->
    <web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee         http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <display-name>SupplyManagementWeb</display-name>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>/</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>  
      <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>  
      <param-value>bootstrap</param-value>  
      </context-param> 

      <!--  <context-param>
       <param-name>primefaces.CLIENT_SIDE_VALIDATION</param-name>
       <param-value>true</param-value>
       </context-param> -->


      <!-- Map these files with JSF -->
      <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
        </servlet>
     <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
      </servlet-mapping> 
      <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
      </servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
       </servlet-mapping>
     <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.faces</url-pattern>
      </servlet-mapping>

         <!-- We use this servlet when annotation @RequestMapping is u sed  -->
      <!-- <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
      </servlet> -->

       <!-- <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
       </servlet-mapping> -->

      <!-- <context-param>
      <description>State saving method: 'client' or 'server' (=default). See JSF Specification 2.5.2</description>
        <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
        <param-value>client</param-value>
    </context-param> -->

    <!-- <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.localizationContext</param-name>
        <param-value>resources.application</param-value>
    </context-param> -->

    <listener>
        <listener-class>com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <listener>
  <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>



     </web-app>`
```

Comment: Can somebody help me I don't know if the css is well setup in my project.

WAR/Deployed Resources/ webapp/resources/themes/ style.css

Comment: I'm not sure I see a question. Or is the comment the only question you have?

Comment: yes Mr lister I think that my code is correct but when I load the page nothing happens!! Is something wrong?